# New checkout pages won't resize to ipad and mobile

Tags: css, html, mobile, scrollbar

Developers made new checkout section on our website but the pages don't size to ipad or smart phone. There are checkout buttons and important elements on the pages that need to be seen by buyers, but they are being left off (pages cut off the right third of page) --

I've been researching briefly for a quick answer -- the rest of our site uses tables and this section uses css and divs only -- is that why it doesn't do it automatically? I'm not talking about media queries -- just the full page resizing to the screen width automatically...

I don't want to use scrollbars but even that solution at this point would give a visitor the ability to actually checkout on these pages...

Can anyone help? It would be greatly appreciated.. If it is more complex, that's fine, but I suspect something can be done to make the pages fit (and zoom if need be)  or (*gasp*)  scroll..fairly easily.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: post the url of your website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that section does not allow scrolling because is disabled from the css stylesheet.

You can get back the scrolling by editing the css. Look in the css file for the styles of `.section`. It will have a `overflow: hidden;` property. (it seem that is stored on file `screen.css`, line 435)

Replace it with `overflow: auto;`

You'll then be able to do horizontal scroll. But in the end, that is not a real solution. Since it seems you are not a coder, you need to get someone to recreate the styles of your website in order to make it actually responsive.

I recommend you to use on your website [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/), which can be used to create a responsive navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the help --  I agree its not the best solution but TPTB determined not to pay extra for the "mobile" compatibility.  My only other question was - our entire site is not "mobile" designed, but the full site pages shrink at least to screen and can be enlarged.  Again, not the best solution but at least makes it feasible to be used until they agree to spend to make everything optimized for mobile.   I'll change the scrolling in the css - thanks for the insight, Chris.

Comment: Did change the css but it didn't fix it --

Comment: @PledgeK. Nope, I've just checked again. Your `/styles/2013redesign/screen.css` file, at the line 435, still have the `overflow: hidden;`. You need to change that to `overflow: auto;`

Comment: Well I think I changed it back after checking it, but I'll try it again.

Comment: CHRIS?  You are awesome.  I'm not sure why it didn't work yesterday, but I just did it again and it works -- there are no scrollbars, but at least they can slide the page over to the call to action buttons.  Thanks so much!